# Android ViewPager, Fragment, and AsyncTask

Tags: android

First and foremost:

*I have Fragment classes which serve as a class for each page in the viewPager.

*Each fragment class has its own `AsyncTask`.

My problem here is that the `AsyncTask`'s of each fragment class are called at once when the class that has the `ViewPager` is called. I know because in each of the `AsyncTask`'s `onPreExecute()` i put a `ProgressDialog`. I am expecting that every time I swipe and go to another page, that should be time when the `AsyncTask` of each of the fragment class will load, not on the first page all at once.

I tried putting the `AsyncTask.execute()` on the `onActivityCreated(Bundle)` but still nothing changes.

Also, every time I swipe pages, the `ProgressDialog` inside the `AsyncTask`'s onPreExecute() shows up. I placed a Log in every `onPreExecute() but surprisingly it prints one time only ever since the`viewPager` is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each `AsyncTask` started only when your `Fragment` is visible, you must execute it from either the `Fragment`'s `onStart()` or `onResume()` method. The reason they're all being called at the same time is because a `Fragment`'s `onActivityCreated()` is called when the parent `Activity` is created, not when the `Fragment` is visible. Take a look at the [lifecycle of a `Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) to see when it would be most appropriate to execute your `AsyncTask`.

Additionally, since you are using Fragments, I would highly suggest using a [`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) as opposed to an `AsyncTask`. They are much easier to manage alongside of a `Fragment`.

Comment: I tried putting it on `onResume()` or `onStart()` but still same thing happens :(

Comment: Try starting the `AsyncTask`s only when you swipe to another page. You can do this by creating a [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html), assigning it to your `ViewPager`, and implementing the `onPageSelected` method to execute the correct AsyncTask.